# DXF export have problems

Tags: export, add-on

[image]

[image]

Hi to all, is there anyone know how to fix this? i want to export blender to touchcad, using dxf format, my problem is, look at the image its only one object, but when i export it to touchcad the vertices seperates, i mean it goes not only 1 object, the lines seperates and vertices... does the dxf export have problems? hope someone will help me

Comment: Not sure but this may be a limitation of the DXF format itself, what happens when you re-import the same DXF file back into Blender?

Comment: i cant try, coz my touchcad is trial only, i dont have the HASP

Comment: I came here looking for a solution myself, though I have not yet found it. However, I will comment that the type of object that you would want in the DXF is called a polyface mesh. It would be a single object. It also allows for each individual facet edge to be hidden or visible. -Joe